# Closure of independence: generated sigma algebra by independent family of events

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

I saw this question: [Independence of events and sigma algebras generated by these events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024523/independence-of-events-and-sigma-algebras-generated-by-these-events#), which made me think whether independence is closed under arbitrary set operations for a given family of independent events.

In other words, if $(A_i)_{i\in I}\subset \mathcal{A}$ for some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ are independent, then are all elements in the algebra $\sigma(\{A_1,...A_n\})$ pairwise independent?

This seems true intuitively, given that for the family $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ any intersections or complements result in families of events that are also independent (as shown in the linked question), and that unions can be re-written as intersections and complements, but I might be missing something here.

This would not mean that if $A$, $B$, $C$ are pairwise independent, then they are also independent, because elements in the algebras generated by the families do not include the remaining event for each pair.